# Setting Component State after Redux has Mapped Redux State to Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to initialize a form with some user information using Redux Forms by pulling the information from my components state. I have a redux action in the componentDidMount method of my component that calls the action, retrieves the information, and then maps a 'profile' object from my store to the components props. The problem is, when I go to setState to update the profile info, it comes back as undefined. I have tried to use the componentWillRecieveProps to see if I can catch the updated 'Profile' props but it is still undefined. Whats the best way to update the component's state once 'this.props.profile' returns the users information?

Here is the component's code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import classnames from "classnames";
import * as actions from "../../actions";

class CreateProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showSocialMedia: true,
      profile: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCurrentUserProfile();
  }

  // componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  //   if (prevProps.profile.profile !== this.props.profile.profile) {
  //     console.log(this.props.profile);
  //   }
  // }

  renderField(field) {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
            "is-invalid": field.meta.touched && !field.meta.valid
          })}
          type={field.type}
          placeholder={field.placeholder}
          {...field.input}
        />
        <small className="text-muted">{field.description}</small>
        <div className="invalid">
          {field.meta.touched && !field.meta.valid ? (
            <div className="text-center">
              <i className="far fa-edit" /> {field.meta.error}
            </div>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderAlert() {
    if (this.props.errors.message) {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger error-message mt-4 text-center">
          <h3>
            <i className="fas fa-info-circle" />
          </h3>
          <h6 className="invalid">{this.props.errors.message}</h6>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  renderSelectField(field) {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <select
          className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
            "is-invalid": field.meta.touched && !field.meta.valid
          })}
          {...field.input}
        >
          <option value="" disabled>
            * Select a Professional Status
          </option>
          <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
          <option value="Junior Developer">Junior Developer</option>
          <option value="Senior Developer">Senior Developer</option>
          <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
          <option value="Student or Learning">Student or Learning</option>
          <option value="Instructor or Teacher">Instructor or Teacher</option>
          <option value="Intern">Intern</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <small className="text-muted">
          Give us an idea of where you are at in your career
        </small>
        <div className="invalid">
          {field.meta.touched && !field.meta.valid ? (
            <div className="text-center">
              <i className="far fa-edit" /> {field.meta.error}
            </div>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderSocialMediaField(field) {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <div className="input-group-prepend">
          <span className="input-group-text">
            <i className={field.icon} />
          </span>
          <input
            type={field.type}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder={field.placeholder}
            icon={field.icon}
            {...field.input}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    this.props.createNewUserProfile(values);
  }

  toggleHiddenSocialInputs(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showSocialMedia: !this.state.showSocialMedia
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    const { profile } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
            <Link to="/dashboard" className="btn btn-light p-2 mt-2">
              <i className="mr-1 fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left" /> Go Back
            </Link>
            <h5 className="display-4 pt-2 text-center font-weight-light">
              Update Your Profile
            </h5>
            <p className="text-black-50 pt-3 font-weight-light">
              * = required field
            </p>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
              {this.renderAlert()}
              <Field
                name="handle"
                type="text"
                placeholder="* Profile handle"
                component={this.renderField}
                description="A unique handle for your profile URL - (Can't be changed later)"
              />
              <Field name="status" component={this.renderSelectField} />
              <Field
                name="company"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Company"
                component={this.renderField}
                description="Can be your own or the one you work for"
              />
              <Field
                name="website"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Website"
                component={this.renderField}
                description="Could be your own or company website"
              />
              <Field
                name="location"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Location"
                component={this.renderField}
                description="Suggested format is: City, State"
              />
              <Field
                name="skills"
                type="text"
                placeholder=" Skills"
                component={this.renderField}
                description="Please use comma separated values (eg: HTML, CSS, Javascript, etc)"
              />
              <Field
                name="githubusername"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Github Username"
                component={this.renderField}
                description="If you want your latest repos and a Github link, include your username"
              />
              <div className="form-control-group">
                <Field
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  name="bio"
                  placeholder="A short bio about yourself"
                  component="textarea"
                />
                <small className="text-muted">
                  Tell us a little about yourself
                </small>
              </div>
              <div className="row mt-2 pt-2">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-outline-secondary m-auto"
                  onClick={this.toggleHiddenSocialInputs.bind(this)}
                >
                  Add Social Network Links <i className=" ml-1 fas fa-users" />
                </button>
              </div>

              {!this.state.showSocialMedia && (
                <div className="mt-3">
                  <Field
                    name="facebook"
                    placeholder="Facebook profile URL"
                    icon="fab fa-facebook-square"
                    component={this.renderSocialMediaField}
                  />
                  <Field
                    name="twitter"
                    placeholder="Twitter profile URL"
                    icon="fab fa-twitter-square"
                    component={this.renderSocialMediaField}
                  />
                  <Field
                    name="linkedin"
                    placeholder="Linkedin profile URL"
                    icon="fab fa-linkedin"
                    component={this.renderSocialMediaField}
                  />
                  <Field
                    name="youtube"
                    placeholder="Youtube profile URL"
                    icon="fab fa-youtube-square"
                    component={this.renderSocialMediaField}
                  />
                  <Field
                    name="instagram"
                    placeholder="Instagram profile URL"
                    icon="fab fa-instagram"
                    component={this.renderSocialMediaField}
                  />
                </div>
              )}

              <button action="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-5">
                Create Profile <i className=" ml-1 fas fa-user-alt" />
              </button>
              {this.renderAlert()}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.handle) {
    errors.handle = "Please enter a handle for your profile";
  }
  if (!values.status) {
    errors.status = "Please select a status for your profile";
  }
  return errors;
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    errors: state.errors,
    profile: state.profile
  };
};

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: "CreateProfile",
  initialValues: {}
})(connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(CreateProfile));
```

Comment: You might have better luck with a more minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure why you want to attach profile to component state. But if this.props.profile is always undefined, then it sounds like you're failing to fetch the user profile or you're not updating the store correctly. I would need to see getCurrentUserProfile and your reducer.

Fwiw, I would dispatch a request for user information from a container and set initialValues to state.profile (if state.profile, is in fact, your initial user data).